# How to use Multiple OR on WHERE Clause?

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem with my MYSQL statement

> Warning
>   : mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in
>   C:\Users\R.B.Lara\Documents\My Projects\focalnews\index.php
>   on line
>   188

```
$sqltype = "SELECT * FROM focalnews_items ORDER BY datime ASC limit $last,20 WHERE (likes >= 5 OR love >= 5 OR informative >= 5)";

$resulttype = mysqli_query($conn, $sqltype);

if (mysqli_num_rows($resulttype) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulttype))
    {
        $profile_pic = $row["profile_pic"];
        $author = $row["author"];
        $message = $row["message"];
        $likes = $row["likes"];
        $love = $row["love"];
        $informative = $row["informative"];
        $datime = $row["datime"];
        $joined_date = $row["joined_date"];
    }
}
?>
```

Any Idea please?

Comment: Always check the errors from the database. You can even run the query directly to the database if you can’t get the errors from PHP. WHERE goes before ORDER.

Comment: LIMIT clause goes at the very end, after where, group by, having and order by.

Comment: Thanks guys sorry I overlooked my code and I am so burnout,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ORDER BY and LIMIT should be goes at the end.

You can use the multiple conditions in `OR` as follows

```
WHERE  likes >= 5 OR love >= 5 OR informative >= 5
```

Your query should be

```
$sqltype = "SELECT * FROM focalnews_items WHERE likes >= 5 OR love >= 5 OR informative >= 5 ORDER BY datime ASC limit $last,20";
```

Comment: Thank @rakesh I will accept this as the answer since you have sample code